# Posting JSON using PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to post some JSON data in PHP on my local server. I have the following code below but it's not working. Did i miss a vital thing?

```
    $url = 'http://localhost/mmcv/chart1.php';

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS,array('Content-Type: application/json'));  


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: did you enable curl first of all in your server?

Comment: check whether curl is enabled or not using this code in your server if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
throw new Exception('PHP cURL extension is not present.');
}

Comment: @Venkat I'm not quite sure if i have. I used curl to fetch data from an API previously, does this still mean i would have to enable it on my end?

Comment: check once what is wrong in checking just do this if you are using Xampp go to htdocs folder create a test.php file paste the above code and run it.If you get any error post it here...

Comment: @Venkat it doesn't work i just get a server error : "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Comment: then do one thing go to your php.ini file and search for curl you will find extension and curl.dll line un comment it and restart server

Comment: @Venkat i'm sure curl is enabled, i just checked my php info

Comment: then sorry dude........i can't help

Comment: @Venkat no worries i've resolved it, Eugene's post below was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your problem is in the receiving script.
Try the following in "mmcv/chart1.php":

```
$rawInput = file_get_contents('php://input');

if(is_string($rawInput)) {
    if(!is_null($jsonInput = json_decode($rawInput, true)))
        $_POST = $jsonInput;
}
```

Comment: thanks this definitely helped! it was a problem with a line in my code

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS,array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

even if you are posting json you still have to send data in url encoded form so send it like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS,array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
```

and use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

instead of

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
```